# Why doesn't the background color of the body tag change?

Tags: html, css

My HTML codes are like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Netflix Clone İnşası</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>

   My some codes are here.
          
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS codes are as follows:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
};

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
}
```

I could not understand where I made a mistake. However, this is a very simple process.

Comment: [Use a validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input). It will tell you where your typo is.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You had a **semicolon** in your CSS file on the wrong place.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}/*;*/

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Netflix Clone İnşası</title>
</head>

<body>

  My some codes are here.

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.